# sql query converting a list to multiple columns

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I am struggling with a query that tries to create 3 separate columns in a 'select' statement from one column....based on the value within the column.

My example:

I have two tables

```
forest.plots
columns = id(PK), a, b

forest.plot_measurements
columns = id(PK), plot_id (FK), measure_type (int), value_real
```

When a plot_measurement has measure_type = 1 this is a slope measurement, if measure_type = 2 then it is a wet_weight measure

The desired result would be to have a table that has titles:

```
plot_id, slope, wet_weight
```

I want the slope column to contain values from value_real where measure_type = 2, and I want the wet_weight column to contain values from value_real where measure_type = 1

The code I have only succeeds at getting one value:

```
select pm.value_real slope, pl.input_plot_id 
from forest.plot_measurement pm 
inner join forest.plots pl on pm.plot_id = pl.plot_id 
where pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 1
```

how do I get the second measurement column? Any help greatly appreciated.

Becky

Answer (score 0):

Just join the table twice putting the desired type_id into the join condition:

```
select pm.value_real slope, pl.input_plot_id, wg.value_real as wet_weight
from forest.plots pl
  join forest.plot_measurement pm on pm.plot_id = pl.plot_id pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 1 
  join forest.plot_measurement wg on wg.plot_id = pl.plot_id wg.plot_measurement_type_id = 2
```

This assumes that you do have one row for each measurement. If you don't, you need to change the `join` into an `outer join`:

```
select pm.value_real slope, pl.input_plot_id, wg.value_real as wet_weight
from forest.plots pl
  left join forest.plot_measurement pm on pm.plot_id = pl.plot_id pm.plot_measurement_type_id = 1 
  left join forest.plot_measurement wg on wg.plot_id = pl.plot_id wg.plot_measurement_type_id = 2
```

Comment: great, thank you very much. Not every row will have a measurement for both wet_weight and slope...and so the latter option is suitable. ...I have noticed that this takes a while to query (once I added a few other types of measurements) though. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to `pivoting`.  One option to achieve it is to use `max` with `case`:

```
select pl.plot_id, 
    max(case when pm.measure_type = 1 then value_real end) slope,
    max(case when pm.measure_type = 2 then value_real end) wet_weight
from forest.plots pl 
   inner join forest.plot_measurement pm on pm.plot_id = pl.plot_id 
group by pl.plot_id
```

Comment: Great, this also works (in addition to a_horse_with_no_name solution above). I have some measurements that are boolean and others that are char.  (i.e. the "then value_real" would be "then_value_char" or "then_value_bool"). These obviously do not work using the "max(case" operator. what would be the solution for non-numeric types? Thanks again for your support. Really appreciated.

Comment: @user3770062 -- you can use `case` with any data type.  Give it a try, it should work.